# transactions in rpc block response sometimes have chain null and sometimes correct chain

Tags: parity, json-rpc, rpc

when doing e.g. a blockByNumber rpc request I am getting a result like this from parity:
https://gist.github.com/ligi/fbc7061d93f087cf0eb0f4db83d1fced

what is puzzling me that some transactions have:

`chainId":null`

and some have

`"chainId":"0x1"`

I do not see the pattern when either variant is returned. geth does not contain the chainId there at all.
Can someone enlighten me what is going on there? Is this a bug or am I missing some pattern/background?

Comment: is it possible some of the transactions are [EIP155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) compliant and some are network agnostic?

Comment: this is exactly right - all of the transactions with null chainid also have a 'v' of 0x1c or 0x1b - 27 or 28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ChainId can be considered to be derived from the signature of a transaction, as described in [EIP 155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) - in the case of all of these transactions, they have the previous transaction format, where chainId is not present, which you can verify by checking the `v` value of these transactions (they are all 27 or 28, 0x1c or 0x1b).

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense. Bit crazy how many people still sign without EIP155